# Is the inter-packet gap is a field in ethernet packet?

Tags: ethernet

In wikipedia the image of ethernet frame includes a field "inter-packet gap". Other sited I've looked in don't have that field. I don't seem to understand if the gap is predefined according to the protocol or it can be changed using this field.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [networkengineering.SE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default gap between packets is 96 "bit times" (the time taken to send 96 bits on the medium used).

This is sometimes too big or too small in very specialised circumstances, so organisations are allowed to override this by specifying their own.

By including this field, you're effectively telling the recipient, "I'm not going to send anything for n bit times now, please do the same".

Apparently, it's too small for some Ethernet connections on MS Windows and can be changed 
[here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315237)